# Laravel union within model functions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, union, models

Hello i am new here and not a native English speaker so please forgive me for any mistakes on my grammar and on my question formatting.

I am building an app with php using laravel framework 5.4 version.
The web app is very simple its for reviewing articles and users that posts articles.

I would like to learn how i can union the results of the functions within my model. 
I want the allReviews function from user model to return the reviews the user has mixed with the reviews his articles have orderby createdtime.

let me explain better.

here is my 3 main tables:

```
Users     | Articles  | Reviews
--------- | --------- | --------- 
id        | id        | id
name      | user_id   | reviewable_id
email     | title     | reviewable_type
password  | body      | reviewtext
etc..     | etc..     | created_time
```

and here is my models code :

```
class User extends Model{

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class,'user_id');
    }

    public function reviews(){
        return $this->morphMany(Review::class,'reviewable');
    }

    public function allReviews(){
        /*
         i want union something like this:

        $result = $this->reviews() union
        foreach ($this->Articles() as $Article) {
            union $Article->reviews();
        }
        orderby created_time ASC or DESC doesn't matter

        return $result
        */
    }
}

class Article extends Model{

    protected $table = 'articles';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }

    public function reviews(){
        return $this->morphMany(Review::class,'reviewable');
    }
}

class Review extends Model{

    protected $table = 'reviews';

    public function reviewable(){
        return $this->morphTo('reviewable');
    }
}
```

So my question is how i can do the function allReviews from user to work ?

Any help is appreciated :)
Thank You

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Calling the $user->reviews property will return all reviewable models. You don't have to UNION anything, Eloquent will take care of that for you.

Try this:

```
public function allReviews(){
    $reviews = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

    foreach($this->articles as $article)
    {
        $reviews = $reviews->merge($article->reviews);
    }

    $reviews = $reviews->merge($this->reviews);

    return $reviews;
}
```

I'm really tired now and I have a feeling you might get the N+1 query problem situation here but it should work for you.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply but this returns only the reviews the user got
i want to return the reviews the user has + the reviews the articles he wrote have and union those results and make them orderby create time.

thank you

Comment: You seem to have a duplicate table name, you use 'articles' both for the Articles model and Reviews model. 

Also, your model class should not be in the plural form. Rename Reviews to Review. Change the Review->table property to 'reviews' and create proper migration.

Comment: ahhh i am really sorry just noticed that and changed it but still i don't know how to make the function allReviews work :(

Comment: the user->reviews only returns the reviews the user has , it doesn't contain the the reviews his articles have.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!!!!!! 
for now it seems to work great will give it an extensive test latter with more data !!!!! Thanks again !